# MonoGame porting to linux

Tags: c#, linux, cross-platform, virtual-machine, monogame

I have developed a game on Windows 7 (64bit) in Visual Studio 2015 with the language C# and the MonoGame framework. The game works fine on Windows, but I also wanted to make the game to be playable on Linux. Therefore I installed VirtualBox with Ubuntu 15.10 (64bit) on my Windows PC, to test if I can make my game running on Ubuntu.
After trying to compile the game in different ways with no solution in sight, I came to the conclusion to ask a few questions here about deploying MonoGame to Linux:

1. Is it possible to compile a MonoGame game in VisualStudio 2015 on Windows for Linux in a...

   1.1. MonoGame Linux Project?

   1.2. MonoGame Windows OpenGL Project?

   1.3. MonoGame Windows Project? (which my game currently is)
2. If [1.] what are the requirements and what programs need to be installed on Linux to run this [1.x] build?
3. Is it possible (and recommended) to compile the game in MonoDevelop on a **virtual** Ubuntu machine?
4. Is it even possible to run a MonoGame game on a **virtual** Ubuntu machine?
5. What is the proper executable file extension for a game on Linux? (Because Linux Project on Windows is only building a .exe)

I have almost no experience with Linux, so I hope someone can answer me these questions, maybe someone who has experience with porting a MonoGame game to linux.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Though the question is a few years old, it's deserving of an answer. I managed to make cross-platform builds for a game built in MonoGame through Mono's mkbundle. [Here](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2018/03/22/bundling-mono-with-a-net-executable-using-mkbundle-on-windows/) is a great tutorial for doing so on Windows.

You'll want to download the latest Mono version and append an "exe" extension to the file located at **C:\Program Files (x86)\mono\bin\mono**. Next download the appropriate [runtime](https://download.mono-project.com/runtimes/raw/) for the platform you want to deploy to, give it a "zip" extension, and extract it into the following path: **C:\Users\youruserhere\Documents.mono\targets**

After that, you should be ready to build; open up a Command Prompt and enter `mkbundle --local-targets`. If everything went smoothly, the runtimes you have installed should be displayed. After that is a matter of building an exe to the target platform.

Here's an example for building an application to Ubuntu: `mkbundle HelloWorldConsole.exe --simple -o HelloWorldBundleUbuntu --cross mono-5.10.0-ubuntu-16.04-x64`

Keep in mind that some classes not implemented in Mono, such as `WebBrowser`, will cause the build to fail. If this is the case, you may need to find a workaround.

With this you can run the file in Linux by entering `./HelloWorldBundleUbuntu` in a Terminal. I've had no issues running the game this way in a virtual machine.

Lastly, if you want to go the .NET Core route, MonoGame has a WIP [core fork](https://github.com/cra0zy/MonoGame/tree/core) that you can use, though I'm unsure how well it works.

Answer (score 1):

To add to an already year old answer by Kimimaru, there's also the possibility to use MonoKickstart to get your Monogame executables up and running on Mac and Linux without the need to bundle anything. This is especially handy if your projects are a little difficult to bundle, because of third-party libraries or otherwise.

You simply unpack the Kickstart archive and paste your Windows executable ontop. By editing the .kick files to point to the appropriate executable, they will act as an intermediary to run your programs using mono (which is provided, as well, no need to install on target machine).

https://github.com/mrhelmut/MonoKickstart